# Using getGeneratedKeys with batch inserts in MySQL with Connector/J

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connector-j

Using Connector/J, I would like to do a batch insert into a master table followed by a batch insert into a details table (`PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` for both). I haven't found much information online, so I'm looking for any feedback from people that have experience with this.

1. Can I use
   `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` to get
   the IDs of the newly inserted rows
   in the master table so that I can
   use them as foreign keys in the
   detail inserts?
2. What if not every query resulted in
   an insert (e.g. there was an `insert
   ignore` or `insert ... on duplicate
   key update` query)? Will I get a row
   in `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` for every
   statement, or only for the new ones?
3. What will
   `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` return
   there is an error with one of the
   inserted master records, and
   `continueBatchOnError` is set to `true`
   in the connection string?
4. Are there any differences in the related behavior between Connector/J versions 5.0.x vs 5.5.x? What about MySQL 5.0 vs 5.1?
5. Any there any other issues or gotchas that I should be aware of?
6. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I ran some tests. With Connector/J 5.1 and MySQL 5.1.42, I observe the following:

1. `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` works as expected for inserts
2. If a row was inserted or updated (the update count array returned by `executeBatch()` returns '1' or '2'), `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` will have the key for that row. If the row was not modified (`insert ignore` or `insert ... on duplicate key update` that results in a no-op, `executeBatch()` returns `3`), there is no key.
3. The ResultSet returned by `getGeneratedKeys` will have the entries for successfully inserted rows, as per (2). There will not be a generated key row for the failed inserts (where update count value is `Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED`)
4. ?
5. Be careful with `rewriteBatchedStatements` in the JDBC connection string. If it is set to `true`, any failures will result in every row in the rewritten "chunk" to be treated as though it had failed. One way to handle this is to iterate the failed rows and retry them without batching.
6. ?

Comment: Note there's some constraints on the table - http://stackoverflow.com/q/7333524/1339987