# Java PreparedStatement multiple batch inserts with foreign keys

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a Java application and am trying to do a series of batch inserts to a MySQL database. However, many of my tables are linked by foreign keys. So I don't know the value of the foreign keys to use because they are generated in a previous batch.

---

For example take these two tables:
**parent**
id
name

**child**
id
parent_id *(required foreign key to parent.id)*
name

---

I know how to import these without using batches:

```
//already initialized variables: Connection connection, List<ParentObject> parentObjects

ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement psParent = null;
PreparedStatement psChild = null;
for(ParentObject parent: parentObjects){
    psParent = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES (?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    psParent.setString(1, parent.getName());
    psParent.executeUpdate();

    int parentId = 0;
    rs = psParent.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (rs.next())
        parentId = rs.getInt(1);

    rs.close();
    psParent.close();

    for(ChildObject child : parent.getChildren()){
        psChild = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO child (parent_id, name) VALUES (?,?)");
        psChild.setInt(1, parentId);
        psChild.setString(2, child.getName());
        psChild.executeUpdate();
        psChild.close();
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to use batches:

```
PreparedStatement psParent = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES (?)");
PreparedStatement psChild = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO child (parent_id, name) VALUES (?,?)");
for(ParentObject parent: parentObjects){
    psParent.setString(1, parent.getName());
    psParent.addBatch();

    for(ChildObject child : parent.getChildren()){
        psChild.setInt(1, I_DONT_KNOW_HOW_TO_GET_THIS_ID_WHICH_HASNT_BEEN_INSERTED_YET);
        psChild.setString(2, parent.getName());
        psChild.addBatch();
    }
}

psParent.executeBatch();
psParent.close();
psChild.executeBatch();
psChild.close();
```

The actual data structure I am using is much more complicated than what I have above, but it illustrates the basic issue. How would I do the above using batches? The issue I am running into is the child objects cannot be inserted without first knowing the parent_id foreign key to use.

I've searched for answers elsewhere and I cannot find anything to resolve this. I read something about using a stored procedure (which I would like to avoid if possible). Efficiency is important here since I am dealing with potentially millions of records. I appreciate any insight anyone might have.

Comment: After `executeBatch` you can get the generated keys, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4952316/3080094). So, first insert the parent records in a batch, get the parent_ids, then insert the child records in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible with generated primary key. If your application is only one client for the database maybe you can calculate primary keys by yourself and pass them directly in prepared statements.